# QLabel doesn't display QPixmap

Tags: qt, video-streaming, qlabel, qpixmap

I am trying to display the video frames in a QLabel with the below code but unfortunately, the Video is not displayed on the QLabel. I have inherited QAbstractVideoSurface into CameraFrameGrabber.

```
bool CameraFrameGrabber::present(const QVideoFrame &frame)
{

    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    if (frame.isValid()) {
        QVideoFrame cloneFrame(frame);
        cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
        const QImage image(cloneFrame.bits(),
            cloneFrame.width(),
            cloneFrame.height(),
            QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()));
        if (MainWindow* child = dynamic_cast<MainWindow*>(this)) {
            //QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
            //scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
            //scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
            child->ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

            child->ui->label->update();
            //child->ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
            //child->ui->graphicsView->update();

        }
        //emit frameAvailable(image);
        cloneFrame.unmap();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see if the image contains real data?

Comment: I found that the problem is with the format of QVideoFrame which it fails to display in QLabel. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is with the VideoFrame format which doesn't match with the QLabel pixmap Formats and also removed dynamic Cast from mainwindow and added a Label in Cameraframegrabber.

```
QImage outImage = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
    myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(outImage));
```